# Inadvertent character strip when reading .txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, text

I have a Python script that reads DB table names from a .txt file, executes a set of SQL statements against them, and exports out a .CSV file with results. The .txt file looks like this:

```
TableA
TableB
TableC
```

I have code that reads through that file looks like this:

```
f = open("table.txt", "r")
for s in f:
    cfg_tbl = s[0:len(s) -1]
    func_1(cfg_tbl)
f.close()
```

(func_1 is a function outside of this that executes the sql, not important)

The problem I am having is, when I save the .txt file and the cursor is right next to the 'C' in 'TableC', the 'C' gets truncated.  I have to save the file with an extra space after the last table in order for it to work.  But if I change this:

```
cfg_tbl = s[0:len(s) -1]
```

to this:

```
cfg_tbl = s[0:len(s)]
```

it errors out with:

```
Invalid argument: 'TableA \n.csv'
```

Any ideas how to read the .txt file without having to account for extra spaces needed, or even blank lines etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using slicing to get the table name?

Comment: You should use `str.strip()` instead. Try using `cfg_tbl = s.strip()`.

Comment: can you use `strip()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `s[0:len(s) -1]` to remove the newline at the end of each line. The problem is that the last line of the file doesn't end with a newline, so you're removing the last character of the filename with that.

Use the `strip()` method to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string.

```
cfg_tbl = s.strip()
```

If there's no newline, it won't remove anything.

BTW, `s[0:len(s) -1]` can be written more simply as `s[:-1]`. When the end of a slice is negative, it counts from the end.

Comment: Perfect, that works as expected and is much simpler.  Thank you everyone